# "cannot find macro" error in the macro's own doc test

Tags: rust

I am trying to add documentation tests to a Rust macro that I'm exporting. Something like this:

````
/// Usage:
///
/// ```
/// let x = addone!(100);
/// ```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! addone {
    ($x:expr) => ($x + 1)
}
````

If I run `cargo test` on this, I get

```
failures:

---- src/lib.rs - addone (line 3) stdout ----
    error: cannot find macro `addone!` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:2:9
  |
2 | let x = addone!(100);
  |         ^^^^^^
```

I can't think of a legal way of adding `macro_use` inside the doc test, so no luck there.

The [macros in Rust's standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/f76d9bcfc2c269452522fbbe19f66fe653325646/src/libcollections/macros.rs) follow the same format as the code above, so I was expecting it to work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Doc tests automatically wrap the code block in `extern crate foo; fn main() { … }` if they don’t find these elements in the code, but to get an exported macro you need the `#[macro_use]` attribute on the `extern crate foo;`.

Thus, you should write this:

````
/// Usage:
///
/// ```
/// # #[macro_use] extern crate foo; fn main() {
/// let x = addone!(100);
/// # }
/// ```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! addone {
    ($x:expr) => ($x + 1)
}
````

(The lines prefixed with `#`  get hidden in the output, but included, *sans* the marker, in the code that gets compiled for the doc test.)

This is covered in [*The Rust Programming Language*, first edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/documentation.html#documenting-macros).

As for `std`, there is an implied `#[macro_use] extern crate std;` in all crates that lack the `#![no_std]` crate attribute, so its macros immediately work.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: do we have a better solution with recent version of Rust?

Comment: What should I replace `foo` with?